# Calculating Optical Absorption Spectra using Ab Initio Computations

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, optical-properties

My main question is, **How does one compute the optical absorption spectra of a molecule by using say, Configuration Interaction energy and associated transition dipole moments.**

I am trying to use an ab initio package, Columbus to calculate transition moments (for $\ce{H2}$ as of now), however, there is some old code, called MELD, that I am supposed to refer to, that somehow takes in 4 non-zero such moments and their energies and gives a spectrum.

The input looks like this:

```
Linear absorption from the 1Ag; qci   
Linear absorption from the 1Ag state; qci   1 
How many components of dipole, and which ones?   3   
1,2,3  
Total no. of Bu excited states   4   
Line width, frequency range, step
0.1,0.0,15.0,0.01   
Energy of the 1B1u state
-1.1724565   
Energies of the Bu states 
-0.677388000000000      -0.262044700000000      -0.245699100000000       -0.245699100000000        
Scale the energies  SCALE
 0.036749d0   
Next come the dipole moments 4
           1           1  0.000000000000000E+000  0.000000000000000E+000   -1.20320100000000     
           1           2  0.000000000000000E+000  0.000000000000000E+000
  0.547801000000000     
           1           3  -1.05742200000000      -0.291179000000000     
  0.000000000000000E+000
           1           4 -0.291179000000000        1.05742200000000     
  0.000000000000000E+000
```

I am not sure what exactly is happening there? A reference to such calculations would be great too.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. You have to be more specific than that, for example start with what software you are using. Then we need to know which level of theory you are employing. That "old piece of code" could also really be anything. As of now this is much too vage to be answered.

Comment: Thanks, I have added details, is that fine? I am new to this.

Comment: Please have a look at the links I posted earlier, especially check the formatting help. My edit might have unwanted side effects, please check carefully. If you have any more information on MELD, please supply it, too. I don't think, that the top google result is what you are actually using for this task. Is [this](https://www.univie.ac.at/columbus/) the columbus  you are using? It would be good if you could post the input to this calculation, too, so that it is easier to reproduce.

Comment: Yes, the MELD code is not available online for some reason. The closest I come to finding it is [here](http://tcam.qui.uam.es/Codes.html) and yes, you are right about Columbus. I just got the set of worked out files and there are a lot of them, my only question, as I edited it in bold up there is about 'how to compute the optical absorption spectra of a molecule by using say, Configuration Interaction energy and associated transition dipole moments.'

Comment: Do you mean how to plot a continuous spectrum? If so, you will need a Lorentzian and Doppler broadening.